# Increase download speed in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How can I increase download speed in WooCommerce for downloadable product because WooCommerce restrictions on download speed and count of connections for download.
Can I enable resume capability for downloads?

Comment: That's a very broad question. Can you be more specific? Have you read any documentation already?

Comment: I just wanna increase download speed for woocommerce downloadable products

@StephanVierkant

Answer (score 2):

You will have to get better hosting, most likely VPS. Or alternatively you can use woo plugin https://woocommerce.com/products/amazon-s3-storage/, where you can take advance of CDN network. I think thats your best options.

Comment: I haven't problem with download product on direct link but when i download file on woocommerce the download speed in too slow

Comment: I know and thats my soulution on that. You can't increase your dw speed without being able to manipulate your own server (I suggest you are using classic webhosting with limited connectivity). Then you need to get better connectivity (switch hosting, rent a server) or use content delivery network (CDN) which posses great speed for downloading.